# react passing groups of multiple props

Tags: reactjs, react-props, destructuring

I have many props (most of them functions) which i want to pass to sub components.

My initial approach was to pass individual props, but later on it gets bigger and bigger, i become confused

```js
 const functionOne...
 const functionTwo...
 const functionThree...
 .
 .
 .

return (
 <Component functionOne={functionOne} functionTwo={functionTwo}....></Component>
)
```

Then, my second approach is using spread operator and destructure on the sub component.
Still, there are many props and i am still confused.

```js
const props = {functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree}
 return (
  <Component {...props}></Component>
)
```

So I try this: grouping multiple props

```js
 const propOne = {functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree}
 const propTwo = {functionFour, functionFive, functionSix}


 return (
    <Component propOne={propOne} propTwo={propTwo}></Component>
 )
```

```js
 const Component = (propOne, propTwo)=>{
   const {functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree} = propOne;
   const {functionFour, functionFive, functionSix} = propTwo;

   console.log(functionOne) .... undefined....
 
}
```

But functions are read "undefined" on the following components.

Any suggestions??

Comment: You might want to google for `object spread` and `Object.keys()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of prop is a singular argument which is why you're getting undefined. You must use object destructuring to pull out propOne and propTwo from the props argument. Here's an example below.

You'll probably want this

```js
const Component = ({ propOne, propTwo })=>{
   const {functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree} = propOne;
   const {functionFour, functionFive, functionSix} = propTwo;

   console.log(functionOne);
   
   return <div>Your component</div>;
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Component
      propOne={{ functionOne: 1, functionTwo: 2, functionThree: 3 }}
      propTwo={{ functionFour: 4, functionFive: 5, functionSix: 6 }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in your **component**. you have to **destructure** your props then you can use it like this.

```
 const Component = ({propOne, propTwo})=>{
   const {functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree} = propOne;
   const {functionFour, functionFive, functionSix} = propTwo;

   console.log(functionOne) .... undefined....
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chakra for my UI lib, and I'm creating a button that navigates using the router using react router Link component and passing it own properties, and the Button properties separately

```js
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Link, LinkProps } from "react-router-dom";

export function ButtonLink({
  children,
  ...props
}: PropsWithChildren<LinkProps & ButtonProps>) {
  const { ...buttonProps }: ButtonProps = props;
  const { ...linkProps }: LinkProps = props;

  return (
    <Link {...linkProps}>
      <Button {...buttonProps}>{children}</Button>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

This example can be used for your purpose, hope it can help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).